# Excel VBA "Method Range of object _worksheet failed

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do some VBA programming but running into a strange situation. The code below runs fine in one excel file but not another, the error in the title appears in the line where I assign `SearchRange` variable.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then
        Dim rngX As Range
        Dim counter As Integer
        Dim wsLeit As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim wsFilt As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim searchValue As String
        Dim searchRange As Range
        Dim rownr As String
        Set wsLeit = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Leit")
        Set wsFilt = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FILT")
        Set searchRange = wsFilt.Range("A4:ZZ10000")
        searchValue = wsLeit.Range("B3").Value
        Set rngX = searchRange.Find(what:=searchValue, lookat:=xlPart)
        wsLeit.Range("A6:B200").ClearContents
        If Not rngX Is Nothing Then
            strFirstAddress = rngX.Address
            counter = 8
            rownr = Split(rngX.Address, "$")(2)
            For Each c In wsFilt.Range("A" & rownr & ":" & "ZZ" & rownr)
                If Not IsEmpty(c.Value) Then
                    wsLeit.Range("A" & CStr(counter)).Value = c.Value
                    foundColumn = Split(c.Address, "$")(1)
                    wsLeit.Range("B" & CStr(counter)).Value = wsFilt.Range(foundColumn & "1").Value & " " & wsFilt.Range(foundColumn & "2").Value
                    counter = counter + 1
                End If
            Next
        Else
            MsgBox "Fann ekkert"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Any idea why this code works in one workbook but not another? (the sheets have the same name in both books)

EDIT1:

For completeness sake here is the full error:

```
Runtime Error '1004':

Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed
```

Comment: Random shooting: are both files saved as .xlsx? If the second one is .xls it may run out of columns..

Comment: Ahhh, that was it, thanks loannis, if you type it up as an answer I will mark this question done.

Comment: Is the workbook, where this code failed, created in excel 97-03 or saved as a pre-2007 format?

Comment: OK that was dumb luck :P I am ashamed to post just this as an answer, so I elaborate a little bit more below..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that pre-`Excel 2007` versions have a [smaller number of columns](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx), and this sometimes creates random failures when the file format changes.

Some Excel 2003 specs:

`Worksheet size  65,536 rows by 256 columns
Column width    255 characters
Row height      409 points
Page breaks     1000 horizontal and vertical`

Excel 2010:

`Worksheet size 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns
Column width    255 characters
Row height      409 points
Page breaks     1,026 horizontal and vertical
Total number of characters that a cell can contain  32,767 characters`

A good practice to safeguard against this problem is to add a "guard" subroutine in the `Workbook_Open` event that checks (using `Application.Version`) if the current excel version is the minimum one for which the file is meant to be. You can store the minimum excel version in the `Workbook.Names` Collection as a constant and check against that constant.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Column ZZ is the 702nd column and excel 2003 goes up to 256 columns only.. I believe this is the problem.